# C# - parse JSON with dynamic and access property name with colon

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, json.net

When getting a JSON with property with : 
i.e.

```
{
    "root": {
        "sim:names": [{
            "name": "Tom"
            },
            {
            "name": "David"
            }]  
    }
}
```

I'm using Newtonsoft Dynamic parse.

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
```

I'm trying to access

```
data.root.sim:names
```

But getting compilation error "Invalid expression term ':'"

How can I access it?

Comment: The colon can't be used that way in C#.  Have you tried something like `data.root["sim:names"]`?

Comment: I would suggest to avoid dynamic and define the structure, but not sure if that is what you would be happy with.

Comment: Thanks @RobertHarvey... Seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

You should convert it to object

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(jsonString);
```

And access it like this:

```
var value = ((JObject)data)["root"]["sim:names"];
```